# Airplane travelling at fixed altitude with speed of 500 mph in a path that makes an angle of 120 degrees

Tags: vectors

> An airplane is traveling at fixed altitude with speed of 500  mph in a path that makes an angle of 120 degrees with positive x-axis. At a certain point, the airplane encounters wind with velocity of 70 mph in direction that is 45 degrees North East.
>
> [image]
>
> What are the resultant speed and direction of the plane?

Okay so I partially understand the question and here is my step by step process.

1) I let 
$$\begin{align}
         \mathbf v_1 &= 500\cos(120^\circ)\mathbf{i} + 500\sin(120^\circ)\mathbf{j} \\
         \mathbf v_2 &= 70\cos(45^\circ)\mathbf{i} + 70\sin(45^\circ)\mathbf{j}
\end{align}
$$
Okay this is as far as I got.. and I am stuck.. I really don't know how to go from here. Mainly because I got confused with how I should evaluate $v$... I know there is a relationship between $\mathbf v$, $\mathbf v_1$ and $\mathbf v_2$ in terms of vectors but the way I visualized it at first was to try and determine the inner angles but I got nowhere with that and then I considered using the magnitudes of $\mathbf v_1$ and $\mathbf v_2$ to determine v but that went nowhere as well..

Comment: sorry. im still trying to learn the formatting on this forum. thank you for the help

Comment: Image (b) shows the relationship between the three vectors. Do you know what vector operation corresponds the "tip-to-tail" concatenation?

Comment: oh.. i think i remember.. it was like the first thing in the chapter.. if i have two vectors and i subtract it i can get a triangle.. but i can also get a triangle if i add it..

Comment: Geometrically, $\mathbf a + \mathbf b$ gives you the resultant vectors of "moving along $\mathbf a$" and then "moving along $\mathbf b$". In contrast, $\mathbf a - \mathbf b$ gives you the vector that will take you from "position $\mathbf b$" to "position $\mathbf a$". Both corresponds to triangles, but have different interpretations. Which do you think is relevant to this situation?

Comment: ah vector addition gives diagonal of the two vectors v1 and v2

Comment: That is correct

Comment: okay so v1 + v2 = v... and i know that magnitude in this case gives me the new speed of the plane

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104002/discussion-between-swordlordswamplord-and-brian).